# Primary key in table

Tags: sql-server, database-design, composite-primary-key

I have table `USERLIST` with `[UserName]`,`[AppId]` and data will be like

```
UserName  AppId
--------  -----
abc           1
abc          18
abc           2
abc          24
abc          29
abc          30
abc          33
abc           4
abc           5
abc           6
abc           8
xyz           1
xyz          18
xyz           2
```

My query will be mostly on `USERNAME` like

```
select applist.APPID
      ,applist.APPDESC
      ,applist.APPTHUMB
      ,applist.APPURL
      ,applist.APPTTILE
      ,applist.UNIQUEID
      ,applist.Domain
      ,RANK
from APPLICATIONLIST applist, USERLIST du 
where  du.APPID = applist.APPID 
       and upper(du.USERNAME) = upper(''' +@userName + ''')
```

I wonder what primary key I should use, a surrogate key or make both the columns as primary key (composite key)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My thought here is making a composite key of [AppId, UserName].

- First, UserName is irrelevant without its AppId so AppId will always be used, therefore it is anyway the first column in the key.
- Creating users is not a mechanic action and happens once at the time, so insertions' slowing down is not much of an issue.
- Depends on your estimations for users per app, the query above may run much faster as your data grows with a composite PK.
- Added by Tony: A composite key will also prevent duplicate rows without the need for an additional unique index on both fields.

Comment: A composite key will also prevent duplicate rows without the need for an additional `unique` index on both fields.

Comment: @Tony Good point I've missed, thanks, I will add it to my answer.